# How to see the process id in Android Device Monitor on Android Studio when debugging?

Tags: android, android-debug

Currently it just shows my device and does not show the process id running on the device in Android Device Monitor. How Do I enable it to see the Process id on Android Device Monitor?

Answer (score 1):

You can see all the processes at the following menu on Android Studio: **Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor.**

[image: screenshot]

Please, specify that do you mean and attach your screenshot